# Get count of historical values based on current value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, subquery

I want to identify how long the users were already in their CURRENT rank... I worked over subqueries and having but it always gave me back all ranks counted which the user were in before the parameter.

```
     DECLARE @T As Table
(
    [User] char(1),
    [Date] date,
    [Rank] varchar(10)
)

INSERT INTO @T VALUES
('A', '2016-10-01', 'Chairman'),
('A', '2016-11-01', 'Bee'),
('A', '2016-12-01', 'Chairman'),
('A', '2017-01-01', 'Chairman'),
('B', '2016-10-01', 'Artist'),
('B', '2016-11-01', 'Artist'),
('B', '2016-12-01', 'Artist'),
('B', '2017-01-01', 'Artist')
```

Which `SQL` statement delivers me for the parameter `2016.12.01` the following result:

```
UserId - CountCurrentRankLength
A - 1 
B - 3

-- Explanation of A: because the sequence is broken on november (when parameter is december)
```

**2 new issues arose (i have changed the original question):**

1. It seems to solve my original issue and will work in 98% of the cases, but as mentioned by *Gordon Linoff* the perfect solution would be to only trace back the time which the user was before he could have been already in a rank, then beeing upgraded and downgraded.
2. Now i have tried to put it into my table function but it seems as it doesnt like the **`WITH`** statement:

But the server doesnt like it as it seems not to be allowed to be used within the function:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure fn_getRankUserAffiliation, Line
>   14 [Batch Start Line 7] Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WITH'. Msg
>   319, Level 15, State 1, Procedure fn_getRankUserAffiliation, Line 14
>   [Batch Start Line 7] Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this
>   statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a
>   change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be
>   terminated with a semicolon.

```
ALTER function [dbo].[fn_getRankUserAffiliation](@StartDate date)
            returns @RankUserAffiliation table(
                UserID NVARCHAR(50),
                MonthsInRank int
                    )
                    as
                    begin
                        declare @CurrentMonth date
                        select @CurrentMonth = dbo.fn_getFirstOfMonth(@StartDate)
                        insert into @RankUserAffiliation
                    ;WITH CTE
                        SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(Partition BY [userid], [Rank] ORDER BY DateofValidity) CountCurrentRankAffiliation
                    FROM PDATA 

                    SELECT UserID, CountCurrentRankAffiliation
                    FROM CTE
                    WHERE [Dateofvalidity] = @CurrentMonth
                    return
                end
```

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: @Booyeoo Which database are you using?

Comment: we are using Ms SQL and the answers look already promising especially the latest ones as they take the date into account as already mentioned by Jeremy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Update 2

Using Row number I couldn't count only the current sequence of ranks, so I had to change the query completely, but I did manage to get the desired results:

```
SELECT  [User], 
        (
        SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM @T i
        WHERE o.[User] = i.[User]
        AND o.[Rank] = i.[Rank]
        AND o.[Date] >= i.[Date]
        AND i.[Date] >
        COALESCE 
        (
            (
            SELECT TOP 1 [Date]
            FROM @T ii
            WHERE i.[User] = ii.[User]
            AND i.[Rank] <> ii.[Rank]
            AND ii.[Date] < o.[Date]
            ORDER BY [Date] DESC
            )
        , '1900-01-01')
        ) As CountCurrentRankLength
FROM @T o
WHERE [Date] = '2016-12-01'
ORDER BY [User], [Date]
```

The first inner query (the `count(*)`) basically does the same as row number, However, using the second inner query it only counts the number of rows where the `rank` was sequential - this is something I couldn't do with the regular `row number` function.

### Update

If the CTE is causing you problems, you can write it as a derived table instead:

```
SELECT [User], CountCurrwntRankLength
FROM (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [User], [Rank] ORDER BY [Date]) CountCurrwntRankLength
    FROM @T
) CTE
WHERE [Date] = '2016-12-01'
```

This will give you the same results as the CTE

### First version

Well, let's play the assumption game. I assume you are using sql server 2008 or higher:

Create and populate sample table (**Please**, save us this step in your future questions)

```
DECLARE @T As Table
(
    [User] char(1),
    [Date] date,
    [Rank] varchar(10)
)

INSERT INTO @T VALUES
('A', '2016-10-01', 'Bee'),
('A', '2016-11-01', 'Bee'),
('A', '2016-12-01', 'Chairman'),
('A', '2017-01-01', 'Chairman'),
('B', '2016-10-01', 'Artist'),
('B', '2016-11-01', 'Artist'),
('B', '2016-12-01', 'Artist'),
('B', '2017-01-01', 'Artist')
```

The query:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [User], [Rank] ORDER BY [Date]) CountCurrwntRankLength
    FROM @T
)

SELECT [User], CountCurrwntRankLength
FROM CTE
WHERE [Date] = '2016-12-01'
```

Results:

```
User    CountCurrwntRankLength
A       1
B       3
```

Explanation:
The CTE will add the number of times the same user has the same rank by using the `ROW_NUMBER` window function with the `PARTITION BY` clause.

Then all you have to do is query the CTE for a particular date.

Comment: I tried to use it in the function which should return this table based on the startdate parameter, but it somehow does not accept the WITH statement within the function... see above.

Comment: Write a semicolon ( `;`) before the `WITH`. Note how I wrote it in my answer.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesnt work, i tried it already but: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure fn_getRankUserAffiliation, Line 11 [Batch Start Line 0]
Incorrect syntax near ';'.

Comment: I see. Well, since you already marked another answer as accepted I assume that the problem is solved...

Comment: Not fully, as there is still the topic with the computation of the sequence when sombody was in the current rank already in the past, and i find your solution more clean therefore i didnt wan to give it up completely.

Comment: the issue with CTE is solved now, now the last 2% are remaining due to complexity on retrieving only the sequence until the rank was another one.. so A should return 1 instead of 2 on the updated example table.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this hard support! It works, but unfortunately only for the example for my real data i get an "SQL Error(512): Subquery returned more than 1 value...."

Comment: Need to change the innerost query.Will try to edit in a few hours.

Comment: Yes!! It solves the issue, i was searching for a duplicate in the month were it didnt work anymore. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Lot of reserved keywords, but here we go:

```
select t1.user, count(distinct t1.date)
from
(select 
    user, date, rank
from t t1
where date <= '2016.12.01') t1
inner join
(select
    user, rank
from t t2
where date = '2016.12.01') t2
on t1.user = t2.user
and t1.rank = t2.rank
group by t1.user;
```

Answer (score 0):

If we assume that users do not switch back to the current rank, you can do this with aggregation and window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.user, t.rank, count(*) as cnt,
             row_number() over (partition by t.user order by max(t.date) desc) as seqnum
      from t
      group by t.user, t.rank
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

This actually returns "2" and "4" for the two users, rather than "1" and "3".  I find the "2" and "4" to be a better answer to your question.  Subtract 1, if you prefer starting to count from zero.

Comment: How are 2 and 4 better answers? User A with rank Chairman only has one value <= 2016-12-01.

Comment: @JeremyFortune . . . They count the rows that match, which corresponds to what I see in the data.  I don't see what "1" and "3" directly refer to.

Comment: @GordonLinoff 3 and 1 directly refer to the number of rows where the `rank` value is the same as it is in the selected row.

Comment: @ZoharPeled . . . Hence, 2 and 4.

Comment: @GordonLinoff thx for the answer, but i could not get it running properly as i  currently dont have a chance to place the parameter properly.